# RESTful APIs Cloud Architecture with MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, rest, firebase, architecture

I would like to share with you an architectural problem that I'm trying to solve in the last few weeks.

> I have to design a platform that exposes a REST API that will be
>   consumed by a mobile app and a web site

Up to here everything is simple. Now come the complicated parts that I have not yet managed to put together. For the moment let's forget about the front-ends and concentrate on the back-end part considering the following requirements:

> 1. the platform **will use MongoDB** (I have tested other NoSQL databases but at the moment this is the only one that has all the
>      functionalities I need)
> 2. must be **super scalable** to provide service, potentially to thousands of users
> 3. must allow **oAUTH authentication** at least with Facebook and Google

I have done various tests with various technologies but I have not yet been able to identify which is the best software stack (or cloud provider) to use to reach the goal:

**First attempt**
At first I started exploring Firebase (which fulfilled points 2 and 3) but had the following limitations:

- Firestore does not provide Geospatial capabilities
- There is Firebase-CLI but in my opinion it is not very usable and
  slows down the development,despite it is based on NodeJs,because it does not allow to restart the application at every modification and
  [debugging is complicated and can be done at most a function at a
  time](https://medium.com/@mwebler/debugging-firebase-functions-with-vs-code-3afab528bb36). Moreover, it seems that the local Firebase simulator cannot replicate some features of the cloud version

**Second attempt**
Then I moved to [Mongo Stitch](https://www.mongodb.com/cloud/stitch) and even here the problems are roughly the same: it is possible to develop locally but (if I have not misunderstood [this doc](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/mongodb-stitch-command-line-interface)) to do the tests it is necessary to deploy the code on the cloud. If this is true, it is an unusable approach because it slows down the development a lot and does not allow to work in a team. Furthermore, the MongoDB Cloud platform does not provide hosting for static resources. This is not a serious problem, but if there were, it would be better

**Third attempt**
I'm trying to use NodeJS (with Express & Mongoose) to set up an environment that allows you to **quickly develop** and **test locally**. But now I have to understand how to bring this on a cloud. I would like to try a mixed approach that allows to combine the speed in development with the power and the features of a cloud system (Firebase probably, because at the end it is the most cmplete platform): I would like to try to develop everything locally, isolating the business and data access components in a separate js library. Then, when I work locally I will map an express route to a business function; the same business function will be mapped on the related Firebase function.
Someone has ever tried this way of working?

Another thing I'm considering is having the runtime deloyed separately in two different clouds. Could there be performance problems? or these cloud services are so performant that it is negligible. Consider that at this point there would be 2 levels of remotization:

AppMobile ===> REST server (Firebase) ===> MongoDb (Mongo Atlas)

What do you think about it? Every opinion or experience will be appreciated.
If you need some clarification, please let me know
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your requirements on Scalability, MongoDB dependency and OAuth, one of the best stacks is to use Node.js and MongoDB. Node.js is known to be super scalable and has library to talk to MongoDB. You can develop locally and push it to the Cloud. One other option is to use Node.js (for Front end and OAuth) and to use a mid-tier Java application (say Spring Boot) for servicing the ReSTful calls along with MongoDB (as the Database).

Comment: Which cloud service is the best, in your opinion, to host a Node+MongoDB application?

Comment: It all depends on various factors (like annual cost, underlying technology, etc.). You can try with the top vendors that support Node.js and MongoDB (like AWS, Azure and GCP).